# How to draw line from the center of UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit, uilabel

I am working on iPhone application,in which I want to draw line if start point is UILabel,also I want to detect the text which is being touched.How is it possible? Please help me.Thanks in advance,Here is my code for draw line.Using this code I can draw line but I want draw line from label.

```
- (CAShapeLayer *)createShapeLayer:(UIView *)view
{
     CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

    shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0;

    [view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

    return shapeLayer;
    }

    - (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
    {
    static CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer;
    static CGPoint origin;

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        shapeLayer = [self createShapeLayer:gesture.view];
        origin = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];

        NSLog(@"cgpoint %f and y %f",origin.x,origin.y);


    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        UIBezierPath *path1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path1 moveToPoint:origin];
        CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
        [path1 addLineToPoint:location];
        shapeLayer.path = path1.CGPath;
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||
             gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed ||
             gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled)
    {
        shapeLayer = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: pls put some code u have tried yet

Comment: The first step is to write some code.  Have you tried anything yet?  Just a warning:  Don't say "no" (it doesn't matter if you say "I don't know where to start") or else you will get the wrath of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have added some code for draw line,but how to start line from UILabel center

Comment: Just get the center of the UILabel's `bounds` (You can make use of `CGRectGetMidX` and `CGRectGetMidY`.  Right now you are using the location of the starting touch.

Comment: I think you should try to handle `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
` , `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea on how you could detect the text you touch, and it actually works, here is what i cooked up:

You add this to the label :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [textLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];
     textLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [tap release];
```

Implementation:

```
- (void) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:tap.view];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)tap.view;

    CGSize blankSize = [@" " sizeWithFont:label.font];

    CGSize textSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font];
    if (textSize.width - point.x < 0)
    {
        // out of bounds
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray * array = [label.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        CGFloat value = 0.0f;
        for (NSString *str in array)
        {
          CGSize textSize = [str sizeWithFont:label.font];

            if (textSize.width + value > point.x)
            {
                NSLog(@"touched str %@",str);
                break;
            }
            value += textSize.width + blankSize.width;
        }
    }



//PLACE_THE_DIFFERENCE_BETWEEN_THE_CENTER_OF_THE_LABEL_AND_THE_OTHER_OBJECT_OR_POINT as width

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, labe.frame.size.width , label.frame.size.height);
    //i used the touch point as an end point , you just need to find the correct rect to draw in and that's it 

    UIImage *img = [self drawLine:rect fromPoint:CGPointMake(0, label.center.y) toPoint:point withColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

  //make sure you don't add imageview one over another so you could tag it and remove the subview with the specified tag

    UIImageView *imgview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(label.center.x, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];
    imgview.image = img;
    imgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [label.superview addSubview:imgview];
    [imgview release];
}

-(UIImage*)drawLine:(CGRect) frame fromPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint withColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size);
    CGContextRef thisContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();



    CGContextSetLineWidth(thisContext,5);


    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(thisContext, color.CGColor);



    CGContextMoveToPoint(thisContext,
                         startPoint.x,
                         startPoint.y
                         );

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(thisContext,
                            endPoint.x ,
                            endPoint.y
                            );

    CGContextStrokePath(thisContext);

    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    return img;
}
```

It will log  the word touched.

I haven't took into account the y, but that shouldn't hold anyone back.

Comment: Glad that i could help, it looked interesting to check which word is being touched.